Are there any other deities whose name is a declension of the verb "to be"?
Are there other examples of deity names in various traditions that are etymologically cognate with the concept of existence or the verb "to be," similar to the way the Tetragrammaton (YHWH) in Hebrew is linked to the root meaning "is/was/will be/to be"?

Have no idea, but I would like to get an answer in the affirmative.

How flexible can we be? Not every language has a verb meaning only "to be", and are compounds included?

@cmw The first answer uses such a compound. I'm not sure if it's quite what I'm looking for. What else did yu have in mind?

@RebChaimHaQoton none of the names given in my answer are compounds. They are derived from verb forms, rather than being identical to verb forms, but there are no other lexical roots in them other than the single verbal root

The names of the Norns of Norse mythology (Urðr, Verðandi, and Skuld) are pretty close to the this, albeit with the verb "to become" rather than "to be".
Urðr and Verðandi are both derived from the verb verða "to become". The former is a verbal abstract, and shares a stem with the past tense, thus likely "[she of] what has become". The latter is the derived from the present participle, thus likely "[she of] what is becoming".
Urðr also has an exact cognate in Old English Wyrd, also a personification of fate. In Old English, Wyrd appears to be singular (and not a triad), but in Middle English we see references instead to "the Werdys" in the plural. Wyrd's name is continued in Modern English as the adjective weird.
Skuld on the other hand derives from the verb skulu "shall", and is essentially parallel in form to English "should". The sense here seems to be "[she of] what shall [become]".
Note that it is possible that the three-fold division of fate in Norse (and Middle English) is the result of influence from the Classical triad of Fates.

It feels like "becoming" is a different verb that "being" even though it has the be- prefix, so I'm not that impressed with the first example. But the Skuld example is kind of reminiscent of the Hebrew Divine name אהיה.

How well established are these etymologies? Are they just conjecture or more widely-accepted?

@RebChaimHaQoton the etymologies are pretty well established (they're all pretty transparent, much more so than the tetragrammaton itself, but not quite as much as transparent as אהיה), but the interpretation (in particular of Urðr & Skuld) is less certain. Urðr is an abstract noun from that verb, but it's not clear it should be interpreted as past tense, likewise Skuld is a common noun meaning "debt, obligation" and it's not impossible that this is the sense of it as a name for one of the Norns

as for becoming vs being, the be- prefix is a read herring. The main distinction is one of lexical aspect. Being is stative, whilst becoming is eventive (typically imperfective). Movement between the two is pretty common as languages evolve, and in Indo-European the root *bʰuH- "to become" frequently develops into forms of the verb "to be" (e.g. English "be", the perfect forms of Latin sum "to be", most forms of Slavic byti "to be" outside the present, and many copular forms in Celtic)

I'm not a linguist, but I'm more inclined to philology. The way I see things, the verb "being" refers to the question of whether something exists in reality or not. On the other hand, the verb "becoming" refers to a pre-existing thing taking on a new form. Given that way of looking at things, there is world of difference between the two terms.

Were the Norns worshipped as independent deities, or were they thought to be simply separate divine processes that happen "on their own" without man bring able to change them (like Fate or Fortuna in the Greco-Roman context)?
